# No puedo poner los dato en un textarea en la pantalla de editar en react con redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Hola** les dejo el repositorio **https://github.com/mauVig/testredux**

Cuando hago click en alguna card rosa, deberia poder editar el card, y el dato no aparece en el textarea.

**Aiudaaaaa** !!! ajajajaja (na en serio ayuda, hace unos días estoy con esto)

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, hay que [elaborar más las preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sean mejor recibidas por los colegas, describe los pasos para reproducir el problema. añade bloques de codigo y comparte el nombre de los archivos involucrados.